# Checking for images on setOnClickListener() in view latency reduction

Tags: android, kotlin, latency

How to avoid checking a lot of images on the press to reduce latency? I want to make `TextView1` green as fast as possible by not losing checking functionality.

```
TextView1.setOnClickListener {

    if (image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.cat__1_
        )?.constantState ||
        image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.cat__2_
        )?.constantState ||
        image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.cat__3_
        )?.constantState ||
        image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.cat__4_
        )?.constantState



    ) {
        TextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        Handler().postDelayed({
            TextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white)
        }, 50)
}
```

Edited:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
showGreen = false
    TextView1.setOnClickListener {

                    showGreen = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear()
}
}

fun isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear(): Boolean {
       return image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                R.drawable.cat__1_
            )?.constantState ||
            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                R.drawable.cat__2_
            )?.constantState ||
            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                R.drawable.cat__3_
            )?.constantState ||
            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this,
                R.drawable.cat__4_
            )?.constantState



        // Do the checking here
        // and set the showGreen variable
    }
```

Comment: You are literally using a delay in the handler? What do you men with reduce latency? There is no async there, is just plain linear code move the content of the runnable at the bottom of the conditional flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend pre-calculation of the state of your drawables that are loaded into `image_view.drawable` and in the click listener just check the value of the state to load the necessary resources.

I am not sure where you are loading this image, however, if this is an activity, in the `onCreate` function of your activity do the pre-calculation as follows.

```
public boolean showGreen = false;

public void onCreate() {
    showGreen = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear();
}

public boolean isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear() {
    // Do the checking here
    // and set the showGreen variable
}
```

And then in the `onClickListener` of your `TextView1`, read the value from `showGreen` and assign the background automatically.

If the image drawable is updated in the meantime, you need to ensure calling `isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear` function to load the right value to the `showGreen` variable each time.

Please note that I just have provided some pseudo code in Java. I hope that helps to tackle your problem.

**Update:** you may try something like this.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    showGreen = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear()

    TextView1.setOnClickListener {
         if (showGreen) {
             // Set the green background here
         } else {
             // Set the other background
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still don't really understand how to set "showGreen" value and where to place code that turns TextView1 to green. If I try to place `showGreen = true` in isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear() it shows me error. You can look at my edited post what I tried.

Comment: Thank you. I use thread to update `showGreen = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear()` regularly every 100ms. And I hope this is the best solution for this case.

Comment: I tried on LG G4 but on worse device but maybe 100ms can be not enough. I actually use 8 images.